# Android: How to change background color of app icon in multitasking view without changing "colorPrimary"?

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I change the background color of my app icon in the multitasking view? Speaking about this one (on the very top):

[image]

I noticed that it corresponds to the `colorPrimary` in `colors.xml`. However, I would like to keep my primary color and still be able to change the background of the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you can apply AppTheme by using a custom colorPrimary in your application tag in manifest file. Then use your preferred colorPrimary for all activities.. It works fine

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/PreferredColorTheme"/>
```

Then in application tag

```
<Application android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></Application>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. It still uses the primary color of the theme that is defined in the <activity>

Comment: You have no option other than to change the colorPrimary. Because after doing some research yesterday, i discovered that even if you change the background color from image asset studio, then that background color will only apply to the icon launcher. But if you specify each theme for each Activity then the background icon color will depend on the colorPrimary of each theme